Visual Studio 2022 : dataset with new tableadapters are not listed in datagridviews
Project in C#, Winforms .NET framework 4.8.
I take a dataset with 4 table adapters, delete 2, added 4, now I have 6.
So, when I came to desired form, and try to relation a datagridview with a table adapter in the dataset, is only displayed the 4 originals to choose.
Of course I saved everything, make a clean, make a rebuild, close Visual Studio, erase bin, obj, .vs, reopen, rebuild and same situation occurs...
the dataset altered
in form, showing deleted tableadapters
What can be done? This is not a normal behavior.
I tried everything about clean and erase files, closed and reopen project, Visual Studio, build, rebuild, rain dance, pray for all gods...

Using agentransack I found the names of deleted tableadapters in the Designer.cs file. erasing their content to recreate them solve the problem... I'm getting sick of this sort of problems in vStudio, sell hot dogs is less problematic, I think
